# Tricky Markov Chain Reversibility

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

[image: Markov Chain Reversibility]

I'm very confused about how to do part (a) of the question. I've set up a systems of equations for the stationary distribution based on the transition matrix but thats too messy. I know there's a more elegant way of doing it. I think the proof of reversibility has something to do with irreducibility of the MC. But I'm not sure how to wrangle it out. After the proof, I think there will be some kind of substitution based on the conditional definition of a SD and the detailed balance equations.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\pi_{ijk} = \alpha p_i^2 p_j$,
where $\alpha$ is some normalization constant that ensures that the probabilities add up to one. To establish reversibility, we must show that for all states $ijk$ and $abc$:
$$
\pi_{ijk} P_{ijk,abc} = \pi_{abc} P_{abc,ijk}
$$

To this end, notice that there are three types of nonzero transition probabilities:
\begin{align*}
P_{ijk, ijk} &= p_i \\
P_{ijk, jik} &= p_j \\
P_{ijk, ikj} &= p_k
\end{align*}

It suffices to verify the reversibility equation for the last two types of probabilities. Indeed, observe that:
\begin{align*}
\pi_{ijk} P_{ijk,jik}
&= (\alpha p_i^2 p_j)(p_j)
= \alpha p_i^2p_j^2
= (\alpha p_j^2 p_i)(p_i)
= \pi_{jik}P_{jik,ijk} \\
\pi_{ijk} P_{ijk,ikj}
&= (\alpha p_i^2 p_j)(p_k)
= \alpha p_i^2p_j p_k
= (\alpha p_i^2 p_k)(p_j)
= \pi_{ikj}P_{ikj,ijk} \\
\end{align*}
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks so much! This is insightful. I was wondering how to do part (b). Im thinking first step analysis but Im not confident with my answer as it seems rather high.

Comment: Since $p_i$ is fully provided to you, you should be able to compute the normalization constant $\alpha$. It follows that the expected number of days until the books are again in the same order is $1/\pi_{123}$.